# Can't npm install ursa, rebuild C++ compile error: Unsupported architecture

Tags: c++, node.js, npm-install

My nodejs project included the ursa module, and when I run "npm install", the ursa module gave me compile error. I also try to install ursa alone using "npm install ursa", but I got the same errors.

```
ursa@0.9.4 install /Users/kenji/node_modules/ursa
node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/ursaNative/src/ursaNative.o
clang: warning: using sysroot for 'iPhoneOS' but targeting 'MacOSX' [-Wincompatible-sysroot]
In file included from ../src/ursaNative.cc:3:
In file included from ../src/ursaNative.h:9:
In file included from /Users/kenji/.node-gyp/6.11.4/include/node/node.h:42:
In file included from /Users/kenji/.node-gyp/6.11.4/include/node/v8.h:19:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/include/stdint.h:63:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/usr/include/stdint.h:52:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:32:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:761:2: error: 
      Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^
```

I don't understand why it mentioned about iPhoneOS, because it had nothing to do with iOS and I'm using it just for macOS.

Does anyone know what happened?
Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to build that module for iPhone?

Comment: of coz, no. I just want to build my nodejs backend server